# Using drupal_add_content_region()

Tags: hooks, theming

I am trying to dynamically add content into a region.

In the preprocess function, I use the following code.

```
function firsttheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){    
   drupal_add_region_content('dev', "I am reserved for development only");
}
```

In the template file, I print the region.

```
<?php if ($page['dev']) print render($page['dev']); ?>
```

Although I am setting some sontents in the dev region, it's always shown as empty array every time.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You going about this the wrong, that function is used for installs/updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things in Drupal someone else has already been there and done it...

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_region_content/7#comment-48353